# Is it a good practice to use php code inside javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, performance

I heard lot of experts saying entering php code inside javascript is not a good practice. I wanted to know if it's true. If yes, then will it effect the performance? or is there any other reasons?

For example:

```
<?php
$num=1;
?>

<script>
var x = "<?php echo $num;?>";
</script>
```

Comment: You also mix HTML and Javascript here with PHP code in the same file. So this is already a triple mix. Don't you think this is a little bit much for a single file?

Comment: It is already mention in StackOverflow. Please refer this Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849935/use-of-php-code-inside-javascript-code?rq=1

Comment: the better solution is if you want any value in javascript, then keep it in your html in hidden field and access it using js

Comment: it is just not easy on the eyes!

Comment: Does it work as you expect it to work? Does it perform in a way you feel satisfied? Is it secure in the level you are expecting? Is it OK for you and your colleagues to understand the code if you have a look at it the next year? Doing this will save you developing time? Then it's good; otherwise it's bad. Try to be reluctant to what many coding gurus say. Many of them lose more time in coding philosophy than in coding itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not good practice.

> will it effect the performance?

I do not specifically know which performance you meant when you wrote that line, but about all performances I can imagine, I would say: Most certainly, no.

> is there any other reasons?

Mixing two languages is hard as it requires proper encoding. This makes things complex. Complexity is bad practice.

Comment: By performance i meant speed of execution.

Comment: I have the feeling that even if there would be a benefit in the speed (more performance) you wouldn't notice. Same for less performance. There most likely is no speed difference in execution speed at all that would matter. It perhaps would be even that sometimes the one and sometimes the other has more performance. - the performance you would get a benefit from is the development speed and performance by proper isolation of concerns and strict data processing and handling.

Answer (score 1):

> Typically, it is bad practice to use language X to generate code in language Y.
>
> Try decoupling the two languages by making data their only interface -- don't mingle the code.
>
> In your example, you could improve the code by using PHP to populate a cfg structure that's available to JavaScript:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126671/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-have-php-in-your-javascript

Comment: what is the advantage of using CFG structure?

Comment: @NabeelSheikh http://cfg.good.is/lessons/javascript-getting-started

Comment: @NabeelSheikh CFG stands for `Coding For Good`

Answer (score 1):

NO it will not effect the performance, but it affects **manageability** and **security**.

In your case, can your javascript function without knowing the value of `num`? or Are you just developing the JS script from PHP? Latter is the use you should avoid.

Lets take an example where `num` was used to know the number of items in shopping cart. Now thats a very vital piece of information, but since its JS, it can easily be manipulated. In such case, you should store such sensitive information on the server and not on the client.

Comment: It's not a sensitive information. It's something like when you enter a particular url, based on the number passed in the URL using get method, a php variable is set(isset). In javascript we check wether the php variable is equal to a particular javascript variable using an IF condition. I hope you understood.

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

1. You lose the ability to minify your JS scripts because it depends on PHP output
2. Code quickly gets difficult to maintain. You will need to scan through PHP tags in your javascript code.

Normally, I declare a global config object and pull it through a separate ajax request when the page loads (This can be a PHP script echoing JSON).

```
MyApp : {
   x: '123',
   y: 'xxx'
}
```

and then access it from my javascript files later:

```
(function(){
   alert(MyApp.x)
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this a bad practice, if the values are dynamic, you can just do as,

**test.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var foo = '<?php echo $foo;?>';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

**test.js**

```
$(function(){
    alert(foo);
});
```

If it is not dynamic values, recommends no need to use php tags

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is that bad. Assign your dynamic PHP values to a JavaScript variable in your PHP templates(as first line if possible) and then call these variables inside your external JavaScript files. And I fully agree with @hakre answer.